# «Услышимся завтра» — правильно ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов, неологизмы

Фраза часто звучит в радиоэфире.

> **Услышимся завтра** в то же время. С вами была...

Фраза прочно вошла и в обиход, и даже в произведения.

> — Ну, не буду вас больше мучить. Пока отдыхайте. **Завтра** увидимся и **услышимся**. А у меня еще дел полно, — сказал он довольно грубо и дал отбой.
> [Н. Андреева. Остров порхающих бабочек](https://books.google.ee/books?id=rxjYCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT134&lpg=PT134&dq=%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=BU7XDHKmjv&sig=k-Oyvm79UlnT3B1slRNrj2Mo3tE&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRhM_StP7ZAhUHEVAKHaJOAp04ChDoAQhBMAY#v=onepage&q=%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0&f=false)

Слово ***услышимся*** не единожды обсуждалось на [**форумах**](https://rusforus.ru/viewtopic.php?t=3408).
Я все внимательно прочитала, но однозначного вывода сделать так и не смогла:  можно или "не можно", приемлемо или безграмотно его использовать?
Хотелось бы узнать Ваше мнение.

Answer (score 3):

**Услышимся завтра в то же время. С вами была...**

Можно было бы сказать **"встретимся завтра в то же время"**, но слово ***встретимся*** нейтральное, общеупотребительное, без эмоциональной окраски.  А вот ***услышимся*** — словечко **зкспрессивно-жаргонное**: оно и чувства выражает, и заодно причисляет вас к "своим слушателям", так как жаргон рассчитан на пользование внутри определенной группы.

**А слушатели реагируют на него по-разному:** одним это приятно, а другие могут расценить как намеренное вторжение в их личное пространство, чем и оскорбиться.

Соответственно, учитывая разнообразие аудитории, **этим словом нужно пользоваться осторожно.**

Answer (score 2):

Это просторечие из жаргона радио-диджеев. Формальная некорректность словообразования в том, что "слышимость" односторонняя (в сравнении с "увидимся"). На радио это, конечно, понимают, но намеренно панибратствуют со слушателем, мол и вы нам звоните. Литературную прозу это не украшает (как и слова вроде "озвучить", из терминологии перекочевавшие в сомнительную риторику), но в репликах персонажей с их речевыми "особенностями" такое допустимо - лишь бы время действия не предшествовало появлению практики употребления слова (мне встречалось "фотки" времён Второй мировой и "откат" времён Первой).

Answer (score 2):

В те времена, когда появилось слово **"увидимся"**, применение слова **"услышимся"** не было уместно просто потому, что разговорное общение практически всегда было сопряжено со зрительным контактом. Хотя с точки зрения словообразования, эти слова полностью аналогичны друг другу, и отличаются лишь тем, от какого слова они образованы: **"видеть"** или **"слышать"**.

Но технический прогресс не стоит на месте, и сейчас мы все чаще имеем возможность услышать друг друга вне рамок визуального общения. Именно поэтому слово "услышимся" постепенно входит в наш лексикон, так как теперь для него появилась вполне оправданная область применения.

Лично я, например, не знаю другого русского слова, которое позволило бы лучше описать предстоящее общение без возможности видеть собеседника. "Пообщаемся", "поговорим" и другие подобные слова допускают любые формы общения, никак не указывая на то, будут ли собеседники видеть друг друга.

Поэтому лично я считаю вполне допустимым разговорное употребление слова **"услышимся"** в значении ***"пообщаемся по телефону или с помощью иного средства аудиосвязи"***.

Comment: _Ivan Olshansky_, благодарю за мнение.

Answer (score 0):

Мое мнение: это жаргонное слово, и вопрос о "правильности" и "грамотности" для него решается так же, как и для любого другого жаргонного слова.